# How to add two different fields using timelion

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

.es(metric='sum:completed','sum:cancelled')

I have value in 2 different fields `completed` and `cancelled`, now I am trying to add values in above . What is the right way ?

I tried above but it fails .

Comment: Like this: `.es(metric='sum:completed'), .es(metric='sum:cancelled')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.es(metric='sum:completed').sum(.es(metric='sum:cancelled'))
```